# Contain links in jquery-ui Tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Hello I am using jquery-ui tabs on a page that is being embedded into different platforms. The tabs work fine but the problem is if you click a link in the tabbed page it exits the tabs to goto the page. Is there an option in the tabs call to make them more self contained or should I look into setting the target of the anchors on those pages, etc?

```
$(function() {
                        $( "#crmtabs" ).tabs({
                            cookie: {
                                expires: 1
                            },
                            ajaxOptions: {
                                error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                                    $( anchor.hash ).html(
                                        "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible.");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your issue.  Your code will try to load tab content via AJAX so clicking a tab will load the page specified by the anchor in your *cmrtabs*  markup.  Remember that UItabs is basically rendering the output of the AJAX loaded page and inserting it into the appropriate container in the *crmtabs* markup.  Any links in the loaded page are now relative to the tabs page (i.e. jQuery code in the AJAX loaded page will not work but jQuery code in the tabs page can operate on the AJAX content).  Links in the loaded tab are not "contained" but are rather now a part of the tabs page.  If you are thinking of some kind of iFrame behavior within the tab, you are moving beyond the intent of the tabs widget.  See this article referenced on the jQuery UI site.  http://www.useit.com/alertbox/tabs.html

Comment: Those guidelines are very helpful and if given the option to execute those perfectly I would. You are correct that I am trying to imitate iframe like behavior and asking if it is possible to do with tabs. Whether or not it meets guidelines is not an issue at the moment most likely the current page I am working on will change soon.